# onclick button doesn't work in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```
<H4>
<b>
<span style="color:blue;cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage(6)">test</span>
</b>
</H4>
<BR>
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
function showImage(id){
    if(id==4){
        $("image4").style.display   =   ''; 
        $("image5").style.display   =   'none';
        $("image6").style.display   =   'none';
    }else if(id==5){
        $("image4").style.display   =   'none'; 
        $("image6").style.display   =   'none';
        $("image5").style.display   =   ''; 
    }else{
        $("image4").style.display   =   'none'; 
        $("image6").style.display   =   '';
        $("image5").style.display   =   'none'; 
    }
```

My `onclick` button doesn't work in Firefox, can you please help me?

Comment: Doesn't work is not an error message nor a problem description.

Comment: Where did `$` come from? Is it jQuery or `document.getElementById`? You've lost a `}` at the end of your function.

Comment: Its a lot easier to use $("imageX").hide(); or $("imageX").show();

Comment: @PeeHaa I don`t have any error it works in chrome and ie but not in firefox

Comment: Where is your JavaScript code?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha He removed it, so I have just added it again.

Comment: **@justin Why do you keep deleting your code?**

Comment: This looks like half `Jquery`,half `Javascript` to me!

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
function showImage(id){
    if(id==4){
        $("image4").css( 'display',  'block'); 
        $("image5").css( 'display',  'none');
        $("image6").css( 'display',  'none');
    }else if(id==5){
        $("image4").css( 'display',  'none'); 
        $("image6").css(  'display', 'none');
        $("image5").css(  'display', 'block'); 
    }else{
        $("image4").css( 'display',  'none'); 
        $("image6").css( 'display',  'block');
        $("image5").css( 'display',  'none'); 
    }
```